# A query on Table1 return IDs, table2 containing rating, how to get SUM rating by joining table 1 & table2 in Just 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Give these table:

```
Table1
asID mID aType rID sNo
1    2   11    212 1
4    2   8     242 1
4    2   7     241 1
3    2   11    547 2
2    2   3     567 2
4    2   2     577 2
6    3   11    785 1
1    3   6     735 1

table2
asID rating
1    1
1    -1
3    1
3    1
3    1
4    1
```

Note:

in table 1:

- rID is unique.
- (mID, sNo) combination is unique. Let say each of these combination create a chunk.
- each of these chunk will have 1 & only 1 `aType=11`. Each chunk can not contain 2 `aType=11`
- asID can repeat in a chunk. Ex, 4 repeat 2 times in chunk 1 (`mID=2 & sNo=1`)

in table2:

- rating can have either 1 or -1
- asID can be repeated many times.

So, suppose user enter `aType=11`, then in Table1 we can pull out

```
Query1
mID aType rID sNo
2   11    212 1
2   11    547 2
3   11    785 1
```

So after searching for `aType=11` we will know 3 chunks:

-Chunk 1 (mID=2, sNo=1)

-Chunk 2 (mID=2, sNo=2)

-Chunk 3 (mID=3, sNo=1)

However, the query 1 is missing the sum of rating info. I need to get the some rating for each chunk in query 1.

-Chunk 1 has unique asID of 1 & 4 (Note: 4 repeat 2 times). And the chunk 1 should have sum of rating = 1 cos in table 2, asID of 1 is +1 & -1 & asID of 4 is +1.

So the final query when user searching for aType=11 look like this:

```
Query1
mID aType rID sNo sumOfRating
2   11    212 1   1
2   11    547 2   4
3   11    785 1   0
```

Can we achieve this in 1 query?

Query1: `select mID, aType, rID, sNo from table1 where aType=11` then what should we modify that query so that we can include sume of rating into the final table?

I am using MYSQL 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you have is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select mid, atype, rid, sno,
  (
    select sum(t2.rating)
    from table2 t2
      join (
        select distinct asid, mid, sno
        from table1
        ) t11 on t2.asId = t11.asId
    where t1.mid = t11.mid and t1.sno = t11.sno
  ) sumofrating
from table1 t1
where atype = 11;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc93/1)

The key is you have to use a subquery to get the distinct `asid/mid/sno` combinations (so that you don't count 4's rating twice).